# Constraintlayout Barrier setType not work

Tags: android-constraintlayout, barrier

i have a Barrier in activity_constraint_layout, and want change it's type based some data from network, but setType(int type) is not work.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_constraint_layout)
    clContainer =  findViewById(R.id.clContainer)
    
    // worked here 
    val barrier = findViewById<Barrier>(R.id.barrier)
    barrier.type = Barrier.START
    
    clContainer.setOnClickListener {
        // do not work here
        barrier.type = Barrier.END
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement `barrier.type = Barrier.END` executes the following withing the *Barrier* class:

```
public void setType(int type) {
    mIndicatedType = type;
}
```

As you can see, it only sets the value of a variable. You also need to request a layout as follows:

```
clContainer.setOnClickListener {
    // do not work here
    barrier.type = Barrier.END
    barrier.requestLayout()
}
```

Once you do this, you should see the effect you want.

Comment: Thanks，it worked.   Why not Google add `requestLayout` in the function ?

Comment: I don't know, but changing barrier direction in code can't be all that common.